# LTspice 60 Hz notch filter simulation

Tags: ltspice, active-filter

I am trying to build an EEG circuit based on the description here: https://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-EEG-and-ECG-Circuit/. I would like to simulate the behavior of certain sections of the circuit to help me to understand the circuit and to facilitate testing.

I am stuck on the 60 Hz notch filter. I have pasted my LTspice schematic below. By the way, I am using "UniversalOpamp2".

[image: LTspice XVII schematic]

While I expected that probing Vout in the AC analysis would show attenuation of frequencies centered on 60Hz, I am seeing only high-pass behavior at Vout.

[image: AC analysis at Vout]

On the other hand, I am seeing notch filter behavior when I probe between R2 and C5.

[image: AC analysis between R2 and C5]

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Nothing, the AC response analysis done by LT spice is correct. They have built a high pass filter. I've also never seen a notch filter built in this manner.

Granted I spent 5 minutes trying to figure out the tutorial, and I can't. They never show the whole circuit. I'm thinking they analyzed it wrong or wrote the tutorial wrong.

I don't know that the filter you have built isn't a notch filter without doing a transfer function analysis to double check (don't have the time right now), but LT spice is essentially the same thing.

Why don't you do this, one up the tutorial and build your own twin T notch filter, you have two active amps so why not use both:

[image]

Source: https://www.changpuak.ch/electronics/Active_Notch_Filter.php

R4 and R5 change the gain and the other components are for the poles of the filter (a notch filter needs at minimum two poles).

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. With R1=R2=265K, R3=133K, R4=250, R5=9750, C1=C2=10nF, and C3=20nF the circuit above has a Q value of 10 and seems to perform well enough for the <30 Hz signals of interest for EEG. Do you think that a variable potentiometer should be used at R5 for tuning? Thanks!

Comment: I would think you could use it for tuning, but beware of parasitic inductance which could change things. If your building this on a breadboard inductance and cross capacitance can also be a problem

Comment: For a more thorough discussion about this *Twin-T* 60 Hz notch filter (with variable Q), please see [THIS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/433588/can-the-opamp-be-safely-removed-from-the-twin-t-notch-filter?noredirect=1&lq=1) question.